# Which version of C++ am I using?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, c++11, version

Currently I am using C++ in Windows environment.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 with Service pack 1.

I never thought about C++ version unless until I came to know about `C++11`. There appear to be different versions like ANSI standard, C++ 98 Standard etc.

1. How do I get to know which version of C++ am I using?
2. If I don't have Visual Studio I know I can use other Compilers like TC to compile my C++ code. In that case how can I get to know which version of C++ the compiler is using.
3. Are the changes made in consecutive C++ versions about Programming concepts or only in Language design?

Comment: There is no C++0x anymore; it's just C++11.

Comment: You are using C++03 (or whatever part of it VS08 supports). You'll have to look at the documentation for each compiler to see what version of C++ each of them supports; in reality, many will only support "most features" of a version, and not be perfectly compliant with the standard.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: To be fair, thanks to the removal of `export`, there's a good change GCC and Clang will reach full C++11 conformance (minus bugs, of course). Microsoft will probably never get two-phase lookup implemented, so they won't reach conformance regardless of how many C++11 features they implement.

Comment: @NicolBolas that sucks, why won't they ever get two-phase lookup implemented?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: "*why won't they ever get two-phase lookup implemented?*" Apparently, I was wrong. They do plan to do two-phase lookup, [as stated in their current roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx?Redirected=true), but note that it's in the "not anytime soon" column. But at least they're *talking* about it, where before they just kinda pretended it didn't exist. They apparently didn't have an AST in their compiler, and two-phase lookup kinda required that. They need an AST to implement other things, so they'll be able to make it work.

Answer (score 9):

It's not as simple as a version check.

Every compiler that supports some C++11 supports a *different* subset of C++11. No compiler advertises full compliance with C++11 yet, for obvious reasons.

The C++11 specification requires that a predefined macro, `__cplusplus` be defined which has the value `201103L`. However, you *cannot* rely on this macro alone. Not in real code.

You instead have to rely on compiler-specific macros to tell when compiler and which version of that compiler you're using. Or you can use [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/libs/config/) to help you detect whether specific features are supported.

Comment: There is a road map for the planned C++11 and C++14 features in Visual Studio: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008? You can forget C++11.
Visual Studio 2010 has some C++11 but it's buggy.
Visual Studio 2012 has better C++11 for some features, but others are missing.
Visual Studio 2013 has new support for variadic templates and other features.
But VS is behind other compilers such as gcc in C++11 support.
You can download free express editions for all these versions.